# Writing UTF-8 string to socket in Java

Tags: java, android

At the moment I use

```
serverOutput = new DataOutputStream(socketCliente.getOutputStream());
```

and then

```
serverOutput.write(data.getBytes());
```

and it works fine UNTIL I add any non standard characters (for example ñ) and then as many characters I add, that number of characters are cut from the end of the file and don't arrive.

Full source code is available here in PandroidAgentTentacle.java

http://pandora.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pandora/trunk/pandora_agents/android/src/pandroid/agent/

Comment: Have you tried specifying a charset name? `getBytes(String charsetName)` or `getBytes(Charset charset)`. You will also have to specify the charset on the reciever's side. Sending some end-of-data marker would also be handy (or prefix a length).

Comment: I get this:- The method getBytes(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments 
  (Charset)

Answer (score 1):

The good this with using a DataOutputStream is that you have the writeUTF method that encapsulates all this for you.

Comment: writeUTF adds a BOM that breaks the file being able to be read at the other end

Comment: no. it does not add a BOM. It includes the size of the stream. The other end should use readUTF to fetch the proper content. If you cannot use this, you need to explicitly indicate UTF-8 every time you switch from string to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use `serverOutput.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));` ?

Comment: Well, the default charset on Android is UTF-8, so I don't think this will change anything.

Comment: then check the server side, maybe the problem is there, you must read strings like `new String(text,"UTF-8");`